# Data types in windows driver development

Tags: c, types, driver

I'm new to c and driver programming and I don't understand how to work with the capital letters data types.
What is the difference between `CHAR` and `char`? What is the difference between `UNICODE_STRING` and `PUNICODE_STRING`? Is it a pointer to a `UNICODE_STRING`? then why is it not expressed like `UNICODE_STRING*`? my includes are:

```
#include <fltkernel.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>
#include <ntddk.h>
```

Comment: There is no `CHAR`, unless it's been declared in a header file somewhere.  What are your `#include` declarations?

Comment: Same with those other types.  They must be declared somewhere; they're not part of C proper.

Comment: `CHAR` doesn't exist unless you have  `#define CHAR char` which it's useless and proves that only char works . C language instructions/commands/functions and everything used in C program are case sensitive.

Comment: I added my includes into the question

Comment: OK.  Which of those includes contains the declarations you stated?

Comment: I think I found it: `<ntdef.h>`. it was included inside ntddk.h

Comment: @RobertHarvey sounds like a WTF, [but it's a serious winsdk header](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/shared/dontuse.h). Maybe not the best name... `<deprecate_banned_apis.h>` would prolly been better

Comment: @JHBonarius deprecated only would have been better. For reference, you can found it in file system driver samples from Microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/miniFilter/avscan/filter/avscan.h)

Answer (score 1):

I found kinda what I were looking for [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/windows-coding-conventions).